# Switching the splncs04 style to (author, year) style

Tags: biblatex

I am using a Springer Latex template format, with the `bibliographystyle` is `splncs04` .

So the text will be something like:
\usepackage[style=authoryear-ibid,backend=biber]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{sample.bib}
`According to the Guta [11]`

I would like to change the format to:

`According to (Guta, 1991)`

I tried adding:

```
\usepackage[style=authoryear-ibid,backend=biber]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{sample.bib}
```

before the `\begin{document}` and removed:

```
\bibliographystyle{splncs04}
\bibliography{sample}
```

in the end of the document (the two lines are there by the template of Springer).

I have the error of undefined the `\cite` command.

How could I change the `splncs04` to the format of (author, year) if 1 or 2 authors, and (author et al., year) with 3 or more authors?

Many thanks

Comment: It is not quite clear to me which Springer template you refer to, but some publisher templates are simply not compatible with `biblatex` and can (and should) only be used with the preset citation/bibliography system. But even if it were possible to make the Springer template accept `biblatex` there are still doubts about whether Springer would accept and could process a submission with `biblatex` (since it requires a different workflow). ...

Comment: ... If you want to submit to Springer, I think your best bet is to stick with what Springer give you. If you don't plan to submit, don't use their template, start from a fresh, empty preamble and only load the packages you need. Of course then you can use `biblatex`.